# Is it safe to use Google Analytics in a private/secure Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, google-analytics

I built a private/secure web app in Rails and have some beta users on it.  I would like to use some type of analytics to track concurrent users on the site, time on site, frequency, and what features/parts of the app they are using.

Google Analytics would be great but I am hesitant to use it because I'm not sure how private the information is and if it would compromise the security of my web app - passwords and other sensitive information is submitted via forms, stored in the database, and viewed by the users.

I'm curious what are other private, web-based apps using.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need details on how Google Analytics handle your data you should read the [Google Privacy Center](http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/analytics/privacyoverview.html) page.

The short answer is that I wouldn't worry about using Google Analytics in your app.